# GCM ACCOUNT_MISSING error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How to get the registrationId ?

I always get the ACCOUNT_MISSING error

MainActivity

```
package com.example.gcm;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SENDER_ID = "45552950387";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
          Log.d("show", "Already registered1"+regId);
        } else {
          Log.d("show", "Already registered");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

GCMIntentService

```
package com.example.gcm;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("45552950387");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String a = intent.getStringExtra("A");
        generateNotification(context, a);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        notification.tickerText = "notification on status bar.";
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Title", message, null);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gcm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 <service android:name="com.example.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

This is my LogCat

```
08-08 13:54:19.844: D/dalvikvm(618): GC_EXPLICIT freed 45K, 49% free 2751K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 58ms
08-08 13:54:22.944: D/GCMRegistrar(618): resetting backoff for com.example.gcm
08-08 13:54:22.944: V/GCMRegistrar(618): Registering app com.example.gcm of senders 45552950387
08-08 13:54:22.994: D/show(618): Already registered1
08-08 13:54:23.224: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(618): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
08-08 13:54:23.224: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(618): GCM IntentService class: com.example.gcm.GCMIntentService
08-08 13:54:23.224: V/GCMBaseIntentService(618): Acquiring wakelock
08-08 13:54:23.464: V/GCMBaseIntentService(618): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-45552950387-3
08-08 13:54:23.504: D/GCMBaseIntentService(618): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = ACCOUNT_MISSING, unregistered = null
08-08 13:54:23.504: D/GCMBaseIntentService(618): Registration error: ACCOUNT_MISSING
08-08 13:54:23.524: I/GCMIntentService(618): Received error: ACCOUNT_MISSING
08-08 13:54:23.524: V/GCMBaseIntentService(618): Releasing wakelock
```

I am sure the sender ID is correct and also import gcm.jar in the project classpath

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ACCOUNT_MISSING error occurred when there is no Google account on the phone.

> There is no Google account on the phone. The Android application
>   should ask the user to open the account manager and add a Google
>   account. Fix on the device side.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#handling_reg) for more information.

Comment: I am run on the Emulator how to open the account manager and add a Google account

Comment: From the settings page you can find Accounts & sync. You can add new account there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer~ I can get registrationId now